# Can I wirelessly download videos from my iPhone camera roll to my Mac?

Tags: ios, photos.app, photo-stream

I have an iPhone4, upgraded to iOS5, and a Mac running the latest Lion updates as well.  The new Wireless Sync feature keeps everything up to date with iTunes, and the iCloud Photostream takes care of getting my photos into iPhoto.

However, there doesn't seem to be any way to wirelessly transfer videos taken on the phone from my camera roll to the Mac. Will I still need to plug the phone in via USB and import my videos into iPhoto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that an USB cable is still required.

The [article](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2349) in Apple Support that shows how to import videos into iPhoto has not been updated recently. Either Apple is still behind in updating these support articles (not likely) or there is nothing to update--in other words, you still need USB.

The [release notes](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1462) for iPhoto 9.2 list the major updates to the app. It mentions that iCloud support is now included, but nothing specific about importing videos wirelessly. Hope this helps.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought...  Thanks for the references!